# iOS UILocalNotification firing more than once erroneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

thanks for stopping by!

I've got an app (two actually) that uses UILocalNotifications, with a repeatInterval. Sometimes, not particularly often (but definitely often enough) the local notification will appear to duplicate itself and fire off an extra time each time it repeats.

So the first time it fires off once as expected but when the repeat interval comes round it will fire off twice, next time it's three times and so on. I'm fairly sure i'm not doing anything dodgy in my code so wondered if it was a bug that anyone else had come across? This has been seen on iOS 7.1.X and on two different devices (iPhone 5 & 5S) but hasn't actually been tested much on iOS 6 or other devices so that might not be particularly relevant.

Comment: Maybe you are scheduling a new notification every time a previous one fires?

Comment: Nope, I only schedule the notifications in one place which doesn't get executed when a notification fires.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can we see the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen this anymore on iOS 8 so I'm chalking it up to an iOS 7 bug!

Answer (score 0):

Code will help.But you can consider the points

1)Before rescheduling the notification cancel all notifications as may be you are rescheduling and not cancelling the before scheduled notifcations.Use  `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` before you reschedule.

2)Check if after schedule you are not erroneously rescheduling the notification with `repeatInterval`.`repeatInterval` need to schedule only once.

There are some changes made in `iOS7` of notification and one change i felt about `localNotification` is if you forward the time in `iOS7` than all your previous notification will not come, that is usual not a problem same as `iOS6`.But bug is it will remain in `scheduleNotificaiton` array i.e when you check count  of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];` it will also have past time notification count which can not come.But i have checked in `iOS6` it is not the case.

May be your problem is due to changes in `iOS7` notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm not doing any rescheduling myself, I just set up the notification and give it a repeat interval so that it fires off again and again, but it decides to repeat itself more and more as time goes by.

There doesn't seem to be any actual duplication of UILocalNotification objects as I'm referring to them in my code and UI and there aren't any duplicates